# How to use VecDeque in multi-threaded app?

Tags: multithreading, rust, deque

I am trying to create a multi-threaded app using a `VecDeque`. I wanted to use it as a shared queue with read-write permissions for all threads. I have the following code:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let mut workload = VecDeque::new();
    workload.push_back(0);

    let mut thread_1_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter1: i32 = 0;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter1 +=1;
            thread_1_queue.push_back(counter1);

            println!("Thread #1: {:?}", thread_1_queue);

            if counter1 == 10 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        };
    });

    let mut thread_2_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter2: i32 = 10;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter2 +=1;
            thread_2_queue.push_back(counter2);

            println!("Thread #2: {:?}", thread_2_queue);

            if counter2 == 20 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        };
    });

    let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

    loop {
        if workload.capacity() == 10 {
            break;
        }

        println!("MainQueue: {:?}", workload);

        thread::sleep(some_time);
    }

    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4e58a9e99fac76b1db9e0ef24eeca6e)
(Beware that it will run endlessly)

My problem is now that the clones in the threads won't update the main queue. Now each thread has his own queue instead of have one shared. As shown here:

```
Thread #1: [0, 1]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12]
MainQueue: [0]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
MainQueue: [0]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
Thread #2: [0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
MainQueue: [0]
```

Comment: Sure, if you clone the queues they'll be separate. You need some form of locking, probably `Arc<Mutex<>>`.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [crossbeam_queue](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-queue/latest/crossbeam_queue/index.html) for bounded and unbounded multi-producer multi-consumer queues. These queues only require shared references for all operations, which can be shared across (scoped) threads, so you don't need to handle shared ownership or locking yourself. Moreover, the implementations are much more efficient than using `Arc<Mutex<VecDeque>>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried with Arc<Mutex>> but couldnt get it to work. Then I cant use any of the Queues. But I will read on, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks I will take a look. But honestly I wanted to use less 3rd-Party Crates.

Comment: @heash What's the reason for trying to avoid third-party crates?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm a fan of having less dependencies and I want to learn. But yes, it looks also very good

Comment: Learning how things work is sometimes a good reason to roll your own implementation. However, another good way of learning is looking at the source code of high-quality crates. In this particular case, the queues in crossbeam-queue use implementations that are superior to a mutex-guarded `VecDeque`. If you access the queue a lot, your threads will spend a lot of time waiting for the mutex, which can in the worst case result in slower performance than simply performing the computation in a single thread.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I already watched into it and you are right. Thanks again for the recommandation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let workload = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()));
    workload.lock().unwrap().push_back(0);

    let thread_1_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter1: i32 = 0;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter1 += 1;
            thread_1_queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(counter1);

            println!("Thread #1: {:?}", thread_1_queue.lock().unwrap());

            if counter1 == 10 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        }
    });

    let thread_2_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter2: i32 = 10;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter2 += 1;
            thread_2_queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(counter2);

            println!("Thread #2: {:?}", thread_2_queue.lock().unwrap());

            if counter2 == 20 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        }
    });

    let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

    loop {
        if workload.lock().unwrap().capacity() == 10 {
            break;
        }

        println!("MainQueue: {:?}", workload.lock().unwrap());

        thread::sleep(some_time);
    }

    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join();
}
```

```
Thread #1: [0, 1]
MainQueue: [0, 1]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 12]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3, 14]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3, 14, 4]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3, 14, 4]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3, 14, 4, 15]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 12, 2, 13, 3, 14, 4, 15, 5]
...
```

### Explanation

`Arc` creates a multi-threaded reference counter with which you can share a single object to multiple threads. Note that the content of `Arc` is **always immutable** because multiple mutable references to the same object are never allowed in Rust.

That's why you need a `Mutex` internally. It creates what is called *interior mutability*. That means, you can use it to temporarily get mutable access to the object, while it makes sure that the mutable access doesn't collide with other threads.

Further, this means that when a different thread calls `lock()` while it is already locked, it will **block** the other thread. This is what is called a bottleneck and will limit the amount of speedup you will get from your multithreading.

Further, be aware that between two `lock()`s, the content of the queue could change. So if it's important that something happens atomically to the queue, you need to keep the queue locked for the entire duration of that action, which further reduces your speedup.

### Further bugs

- I think you mix up `.capacity()` and `.len()`.
- You should do something with the `Result` of `.join()`, which I here will simply `.unwrap()`.
- `.len() == 10` won't work in a multi-threaded scenario, because it could jump directly from `9` to `11`. So for multi-threaded scenarios, it's better to do `>= 10`, which will  always work.

Fixed code that doesn't run forever:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let workload = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()));
    workload.lock().unwrap().push_back(0);

    let thread_1_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_1 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter1: i32 = 0;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter1 += 1;
            thread_1_queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(counter1);

            println!("Thread #1: {:?}", thread_1_queue.lock().unwrap());

            if counter1 == 10 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        }
    });

    let thread_2_queue = workload.clone();
    let thread_2 = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut counter2: i32 = 10;
        let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

        loop {
            counter2 += 1;
            thread_2_queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(counter2);

            println!("Thread #2: {:?}", thread_2_queue.lock().unwrap());

            if counter2 == 20 {
                break;
            }

            thread::sleep(some_time);
        }
    });

    let some_time = time::Duration::from_millis(50);

    loop {
        if workload.lock().unwrap().len() >= 10 {
            break;
        }

        println!("MainQueue: {:?}", workload.lock().unwrap());

        thread::sleep(some_time);
    }

    thread_1.join().unwrap();
    thread_2.join().unwrap();
}
```

```
Thread #1: [0, 1]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4]
MainQueue: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18, 8]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18, 8, 19]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18, 8, 19, 9]
Thread #2: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18, 8, 19, 9, 20]
Thread #1: [0, 1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 14, 4, 15, 5, 16, 6, 17, 7, 18, 8, 19, 9, 20, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I understood the ARC and Mutex requirements. The capacity was just for debugging purposes but yes i should have made bigger or equal, i will keep it in mind for the next time.

Comment: Capacity is how much it could possibly hold without reallocation, len is how much it actually holds. Just fyi, although you were probably already aware of the concepts.